# Validation for dropdown values to be made in jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm having 3 dropdown boxes to select preferences as first second and third, in this all three preferences should not be same. By the same time if i select only two preferences then preferences should be like first preference and second preference.

i have already tried Jquery validation.

```
function validatePreferenceOrder() {
    var strPref1 = $("#preference_1").val();
    var strPref2 = $("#preference_2").val();
var strPref3 = $("#preference_3").val();

if (strPref1 == strPref2 || strPref2 == strPref3 || strPref3 == strPref1) {
    showErrors("Oops Preference order cannot be same");
} else if (strPref1 == "") {
    showErrors("Oops Preference order cannot be empty");
} else {
    if (strPref1 != 1 || strPref2 != 1 || strPref3 != 1) {
        showErrors("Atleast one preference order should be first preference");
   } else {
   alert("validated");
}
}
```

Actual Result
* if 2 dropdowns are available only first and second preferences can be selected.
* if one dropdown is selected then only first preference can be selected.

Comment: Why dont your write a function that would take the preference number as an argument and gets called on change of each field, checking that you havent selected a preference that is already selected.

Comment: if you post your html I can help you further

Comment: @sjdm, here by i have attached js fiddle link with html [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Adhiyan_8396/frwxd10p/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement from

```
if (strPref1 == strPref2 || (strPref2 == strPref3) || strPref3 == strPref1) {
  alert("Oops Preference order cannot be same");
} else if (strPref1 == "") {
  alert("Oops Preference order cannot be empty");
} else {
  alert("Validated");
}
```

to

```
if (strPref1 == "") {
  alert("Oops Preference order cannot be empty");
} else if (strPref1 == strPref2 || (strPref2 == strPref3 && strPref2 != '') || strPref3 == strPref1) {
  alert("Oops Preference order cannot be same");
} else {
  alert("Validated");
}
```

That way it will only count the second and third preferences as being the same if they aren't empty

Comment: Can you please help me out with the following validation also, if i have only 2 drop down boxes, there is a possibility to select preferences as second and third which should not be allowed. Atleast one of the dropdown should have first preference and so is the second dropdown.